# Show the div content once hover to a different div

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hi This is a different scenario. i have a text-info div with a div inside it what im trying to do is show the div inside the text-info once you hove the a.link on a different div but i tried different steps or approach its still the same. im trying to make it happen using css because im not good in javascript but if you can help me out, i greatly appreciate it :)

CSS

```
#economics, #workforce{
  display: none;
}

    a.link:hover ~ .text-info #economics {
    display: block !important;

}
a.link:hover + .text-info #economics {
display: block !important;
```

}

HTML

```
  <div class="row">
    <!-- Main Div -->
    <div class="col-md-12 mainpsg">
    <!-- End Main Div -->

      <!-- First Main Div -->
      <div class="col-md-5 mainpsg-desc col-sm-5 animated fadeInLeft">

            <div class="text-info">
              <div id="economics">blabla sadasdasdsadas</div>  <!-- show this div when hover from the a.link-->
              <div id="workforce">blablabla</div> <!-- show this div when hover from the a.link-->
            </div>

      </div>
      <!-- END First Main Div -->

      <!-- SECOND Main Div -->
      <div class="col-md-7 main-entrypg col-colang">
      <div class="colcolvan">


      <a href="" class="link" id="una" target="_blank">

        <div class="entry-gorup eg-01">
          <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/1.png" class="first-img animated fadeInDown">
          <div class="hover-link animated fadeInUp">
            <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/external-link-symbol.png">
          </div>
        </div>

      </a>

      </div>
      </div>
      <!-- END SECOND Main Div -->


    <!-- Main Div -->
    </div>
    <!-- End Main Div -->

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: want to do this without javascript ?

Comment: @Taki with or without javascript would be fine, but im not good in javascript

Comment: ok, add the javascript tag to your question so people can understand better

Comment: @Taki sure thank you!

Comment: i see you have only one `a.link` , so you want both #economics and workforce to be shown when the mouse is over `a.link`  ?

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#second, #third').hover(function(){
        $('#economics').addClass('show');
    },
    function(){
        $('#economics').removeClass('show');
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: i can't see `#second` nor `#third` in his html .. and .. did you read the comments in the html in the question ? he wants to show / hide two divs not just `#economics` .. it would be nice if you explain your solution instead of just throwing a couple of lines in a gray box.

Answer (score 0):

To work with pure css using(~ and +)

```
 a.link:hover ~ .text-info{display:block;}

 a.link:hover + .text-info{display:block;}
```

The <div class="text-info"></div> should follow right next to the <a class="link" href="">hover me</a>

or else it with not work in css you can use js function like .show() and .hide()

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.link').on('mouseover', function(){
        $('.text-info').show();
      
    });
    $('.link').on('mouseout', function(){
        $('.text-info').hide();
    });

})
```

```css
.link2:hover ~ .text-info2{display:block; transition:all 0.5s ease-in;}

.test:hover + .show{display:block;}
.show{display:none;}

.text-info{display:none;}
.text-info2{display:none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href="" class="link" id="una" target="_blank">HOVER ME! (JS)</a>
<div class="text-info">
  <div id="economics">blabla sadasdasdsadas</div>
   <div id="workforce">blablabla</div>
</div>

<br/>
<br/>
without jquery or javascript : to do this your hidden element should be the next element of the other triggering element 
<a href="#" class="test">trigger show (~, +) in css</a><span class="show">I will show up if you hover the ahead element.</span>
<br/>
<br/>

<font class="link2">HOVER ME! (CSS) </font>
<div class="text-info2">
  <div id="economics">blabla sadasdasdsadas</div>
   <div id="workforce">blablabla</div>
</div>
```